# GetAll() in a cloud.google.com/go/datastore Transaction{}?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-golang

I need to run an equivalent of this, but in a transaction:
`db.GetAll(ctx, datastore.NewQuery("Items").Ancestor(pkey), &itemContainers)`

But the `Transaction{}` type does not seem to have a `GetAll()` method. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use queries in transactions you should attach your [transaction to the query](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Query.Transaction).  E.g.

```
q = datastore.NewQuery("Items").Ancestor(pkey).Transaction(tx)
db.Getall(ctx, q, &itemContainers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need transactions for `GetAll()`, you can simply call it on your `*Client` variable.

Transactions are for sets of atomic operations that need to be run or rolled back all at once. If you have a set of keys you need to fetch, for example, you'd call `GetMulti()` on the `Transaction` type: https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Transaction.GetMulti

`GetAll` can be done with a single operation, it doesn't need to be batched in a transaction: https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Client.GetAll